# Ruby Hash with Array Values -- Emptying itself

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary

I am trying to create a hash with values as arrays. I am adding elements to those arrays, but for some reason, the hash becomes empty after it runs. I'm not sure why at all. Here is my code

```
def function(words)
  hash = Hash.new([])  # default value of empty list
  words.each do |word|
    sorted = word.chars.sort.join  # sort the string
    hash[sorted] << word
    ## hash becomes empty here
  end
  return hash
end

puts function ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four']
```

I'm new to Ruby and I have no idea why the hash is emptying it self. I've written a similar algorithm with the same logic in Python and it works absolutely fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are your actual and expected results?

Comment: The appended elements added to the key's value (a list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the default hash value you give is a mutable value (partially, at least—see below), you need to instead use `Hash.new`’s block parameter:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
```

You get the correct result:

```
function ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four']
#=> {"acrs"=>["cars", "racs"],
#    "for"=>["for"],
#    "aeoopstt"=>["potatoes"],
#    "foru"=>["four"]}
```

The problem with what you have is that `hash[sorted]` returns `[]`, but never actually assigns to it. So you change the array, but never put it in the hash. If you use `+=` instead (leaving your `Hash.new([])`, you can that this also works:

```
hash[sorted] += [words]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? And how a mutable value gives wrong values? Thanks

Comment: @Darksky Expanded a bit.

Answer (score -2):

#### Assign Values to Hash Keys With `=`

You can fix your code easily by replacing `hash[sorted] << word` with the following:

```rb
hash[sorted] = word
```

That's the only change you actually needed to make your original code work. Consider:

```rb
def function(words)
  hash = Hash.new([])
  words.each do |word|
    sorted = word.chars.sort.join
    hash[sorted] = word
  end
  return hash
end
```

which returns:

```rb
function %w[cars for potatoes racs four]
# => {"acrs"=>"racs", "for"=>"for", "aeoopstt"=>"potatoes", "foru"=>"four"}
```

almost as you expected. In your posted example, *word* is a string, not an array. If you don't want to just fix the assignment, but to also cast the hash values as arrays, see the suggested refactoring below.

#### Your Code Refactored

There are a number of ways you can clean this up your original method. For example, here's one way to refactor your code so that it's more idiomatic and easier to read.

```rb
def sort_words words
  hash = {}
  words.map { |word| hash[word.chars.sort.join] = Array(word) }
  hash
end

sort_words %w[cars for potatoes racs four]
# => {"acrs"=>["racs"], "for"=>["for"], "aeoopstt"=>["potatoes"], "foru"=>["four"]}
```

Other refactorings are certainly possible---Ruby is a very flexible and expressive language---but this should get you started on the right path.

Comment: The value of the key in the has is an array and I'd like to append to that array. How can I do so? I looked online and I saw that doing `<<` would append it to the hash's key's value (which is an array). If I run it quickly on `irb` with one value it works. Try `hash = Hash.new([]); hash[1] << "hello"; hash[1] << "bye"` in `irb`. key `1` in the hash will have a value of `["hello", "key"]`

Comment: This is wrong, the OP is not calling `<<` on the hash, but the value stored at `hash[sorted]`.

Comment: @Darksky I've updated the answer to address your requirement to cast the hash values as arrays, and provided a possible refactoring to make the *intent* of your code clearer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Doesn't matter; `<<` is still the incorrect operator. Consider `h = Hash.new; h['foo'] << 'bar'`, which raises `NoMethodError: undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass`. However, `h = Hash.new; h['foo'] = 'bar'` works just fine.

Comment: @CodeGnome Except the OP didn’t call `Hash.new`, they called `Hash.new([])` which means `h['foo']` (or any call to `[]` on `h`) will return an array by default, which *does* respond to `<<`.